# Swap text in Pure CSS-Checkbox-label when checked

Tags: css, checkbox, accordion, display

I have this Pure-CSS accordion I like but there is one feature I would like to add to it: I would like the labels to change depending on the checkbox state AND to achieve this without JavaScript.

So,

- If the checkbox is **unchecked** I'd like the question text to read as "more info",
- If the checkbox is **checked** for the question text to read "less info".

I don't care what kind of elements you use per se.. you don't have to have the `label` element be the element that changes. However, It is important that the solution continues to allow the user to open the accordion by either clicking the text in the `label` element or the plus-sign inside of class `plus` trigger the toggle. The answer needs to also be free of JavaScript.

*One note: solutions that avoid putting the question text into place with pseudoelements will be preferred over ones that do. The reason: I want to use `first-line` to style the first-line of the question-text, and because you cannot combine pseudoelements, the use of a PE to place the question-text would prevent me from using `first-line`.*

I'm eager to see if this can be done! Thanks!
This is the codepen:
http://codepen.io/ihatecoding/pen/oZjVPG

This is the snippet:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,800);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: #eee;
}


.question-content {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 60px 0 0;
}


.question {
  position: relative;
  background: #8FBC8F;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px;
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answers {
  background: #999;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: .7s ease;
  -o-transition: .7s ease;
  transition: .7s ease;
}

.questions:checked ~ .answers{
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 15px;
}

.plus {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 100%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;    
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.questions:checked ~ .plus {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.questions {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="question-content">
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="question1" name="q"  class="questions">
  <div class="plus">+</div>
  <label for="question1" class="question">
    More Info Q1
  </label>
  <div class="answers">
    What if the answer is really long and wraps the whole page and you never want to finish it but you have to because its the answer!
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="question2" name="q" class="questions">
  <div class="plus">+</div>
  <label for="question2" class="question">
    More Info Q2
  </label>
  <div class="answers">
    short!
  </div>
</div>
  
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="question3" name="q" class="questions">
  <div class="plus">+</div>
  <label for="question3" class="question">
    More Info Q3
  </label>
  <div class="answers">
    This is the answer!
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this by using the CSS [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property as seen below and by removing your existing "More Info" text :

```
.questions ~ .question::before{
  content: 'More Info '
}

.questions:checked ~ .question::before{
  content: 'Less Info '
}
```

The use of the `::before` pseudo elements will ensure that the content is placed before your existing "Qx" so that you get the appearance that you are looking for.

**Example**

[image]

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,800);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: #eee;
}

.question-content {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 60px 0 0;
}

.question {
  position: relative;
  background: #8FBC8F;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answers {
  background: #999;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: .7s ease;
  -o-transition: .7s ease;
  transition: .7s ease;
}

.questions:checked~.answers {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 15px;
}

.questions~.question::before {
  content: 'More Info '
}

.questions:checked~.question::before {
  content: 'Less Info '
}

.plus {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 100%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.questions:checked~.plus {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.questions {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="question-content">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="question1" name="q" class="questions">
    <div class="plus">+</div>
    <label for="question1" class="question">
    Q1
  </label>
    <div class="answers">
      What if the answer is really long and wraps the whole page and you never want to finish it but you have to because its the answer!
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="question2" name="q" class="questions">
    <div class="plus">+</div>
    <label for="question2" class="question">
    Q2
  </label>
    <div class="answers">
      short!
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="question3" name="q" class="questions">
    <div class="plus">+</div>
    <label for="question3" class="question">
    Q3
  </label>
    <div class="answers">
      This is the answer!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good, but you are using the pseudoelement `before`, can you modify so you don't have to use that?

Comment: I don't know if you'll be able to get around not using it (in pure CSS) as the documentation for `content` explicit states that it is used in conjunction with either a `::before` or `::after` pseudo element.

Comment: Perhaps you can use divs then? I don't care about the text being inside a label per se, but only that clicking on EITHER the text OR the plus-sign trigger the change. If you use the existing pseudoelements, I don't mind, but the reason is I would like to be able to use  the PE `first-line` to style my question. You can't combine the `first-line` with another pseudoelement.

Comment: Why you don't want pseudoelements @CoderScissorhands ?, it can be done without them, just using extra elements inside the labels

Comment: See above, nice gif!